# How to read inline parameters using command line args in bash script?

Tags: bash

I have a `bash script` which takes few `command line args` and a `filename` as inline parameter. I am not able to read the inline parameter.

```
sh test.sh -a a -b b -c c < pwd.txt
```

`test.sh` has

```
if [ $# = 0 ] 
then
    echo $USAGE >&2
    exit $STATUS_ERROR_FAIL
fi

# Parse command line options.
while getopts a:b:c: OPT; 
do
case "$OPT" in
a)
    a="$OPTARG"
    ;;
b)
    b="$OPTARG"
    ;;
c)
    c="$OPTARG"
    ;;
\?)
    # getopts issues an error message
    echo $USAGE 
    exit $STATUS_ERROR_FAIL
    ;;
esac
done

shift $((OPTIND-1))
echo "1=$1"
```

Comment: "I have a bash script" - so why are you running it using `sh`?   This works as I expect it, what do you mean by "the inline parameter"?  OPTARG works fine.  Could you please describe the error you are getting and show an example?

Comment: OK, the question has been edited - please check the edit.  Where are you supplying the filename on the command-line?  In your previous version you supplied `test.sh` as the filename.

Comment: Is your confusion `< pwd.txt`?  That is redirection and will be removed by the shell when the command is run.

Answer (score 0):

your script is working fine, your error is

```
echo "1=$1"
```

if you want to see your parameter you should add an `echo/print` in your `case`

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $# = 0 ]
then
    echo $USAGE >&2
    exit $STATUS_ERROR_FAIL
fi


# Parse command line options.
while getopts a:b:c: OPT;
do
case "$OPT" in
a)
    a="${OPTARG}"
        echo "a[$a]"
    ;;
b)
    b="${OPTARG}"
        echo "b[$b]"
    ;;
c)
    c="${OPTARG}"
        echo "c[$c]"
    ;;
\?)
    # getopts issues an error message
    echo $USAGE
    exit $STATUS_ERROR_FAIL
    ;;
esac
done

shift $((OPTIND-1))
```

or 
you can add the `echo/print` at the end of the script.. it's depend by your needs

output

```
[shell] ➤ ./t -a 1 -b 2 -c 3
a[1]
b[2]
c[3]
```

Regards

Claudio